# How to select a maximum value in group mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables: people and log

```
CREATE TABLE people(id int,name varchar(20),surname varchar(20));
CREATE TABLE log(id int,log_date date);
```

and I need show all users with they last log.
Data to test:

```
INSERT INTO people VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith'), (2, 'Elisabeth', 'Taylor'), (3, 'Peter', 'Jackson');
INSERT INTO log VALUES (1,'2014-02-20'),(1,'2014-02-22'),(1,'2014-02-25'),(1,'2014-03-12'),(1,'2014-04-03'),(2,'2014-02-20'),(3,'2014-03-23'),(3,'2014-03-27'),(3,'2014-04-01');
```

I have this code, so far:

```
SELECT name,surname,log_date    
FROM  people JOIN log USING(id)
GROUP BY id,log_date DESC;
```

but I don't know how can I show only one last log for each user.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT people.id, name, surname, MAX(log_date) AS log_date FROM people INNER JOIN
    log ON people.id = log.id
GROUP BY people.id, name, surname
```

optionally add:

```
ORDER BY log_date DESC
```

if you want to sort by descending log dates in the result set

Answer (score 0):

```
            SELECT min(name), min(surname), max(log_date)
            FROM people p1 JOIN log l1
            ON p1.id=i1.id
            GROUP BY id;
```

Not tested but that should do.